# How to get a document from a collection based on a particular field in that document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const docRef = firestore.collection("orders").document("")
```

I need to get the document "147OiRKFYKA3WAo5d5mk" if the field value is Admno:"11.11.1111"

here is my database 
[image: screenshot of database]

Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case is mentioned in the [official Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
db.collection("orders").where("Admno", "==", "11.11.1111")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); //here's your doc
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

I strongly recommend reading [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) if you're getting started with Firestore.

Comment: Thank you, but does this work `const docRef = firestore.collection("orders").document(doc.id);` ,cos i am getting an error _Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firestore.collection(...).document is not a function_ at the code line  `docRef.add({`

Comment: Once again I must point you to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). `document()` is not a function. You must use `const docRef = firestore.collection("orders").doc(doc.id);`

Comment: Thank you, it cleared the problem, but docRef.add created another document to input the new field and docRef.set replaces the value of old field with new one, is there any way i can keep both the values in the same field.

Comment: Yes, you just have to pass a different id to your `doc()` function

Comment: I'm quite late to the party, but I have to ask, is there any way to treat the document ID as a field? I have been unable to find a swift solution to this, though in other languages there seems to be some sort of query similar to: where(firebase.firestore.FieldPaths.documentId, "==", variableToQueryAgainst)