# Proper way to setup Firestore-database for friendlist-system

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im very new to Android development. At the moment I am trying to develop my first app. My app is going to have a friend-system. Im trying to setup the Firestore-database to match my conditions.
I want to use the UserID provided by the google authentication to control the access of the database.

Every user has a friendlist of usernames,since I think, its not safe to let any client know the UserID of another client.

My Firestore database looks like this:

- "users" (collection)

  - UserID (document)

    - DisplayName, Username (fields)
- "friendlist"

  - UserID

    - Username1,Username2,Username3...

Everytime I want to access data of a user inside my friendlist a have to retrieve data from the users-collection using the UserID-document. Since the client isnt allowed to know the UserID of the friend, I need another collection which I am planing to access through cloud functions to know which userID belongs to the username.

- "usernames" (collection)

  - Username (document)

    - UserID (fields)

Is there a better way to minimize database-reads while protecting database accesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking for the UserID(document) based on the Username filed taking the answer from [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247511/how-to-get-a-document-from-a-collection-based-on-a-particular-field-in-that-docu) as a starting point.

Nevertheless, you would need to make sure that the Usernames do not repeat as this may cause issues later on by programming a check in the insertion of updates of usernames.

Otherwise, the solution you are planning would work although with the caveat that you may get a higher billing in the future as you are billed for every read as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations).

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thank you. This helps alot. I cant find any Information about the perfomance of the where-clause. Dont the queries tend to be long when i have a lot of document entries while searching for a field? It doesnt matter for my app, since its only made for a small group of people, but I still would aim for using optimized techniques as if I would devolop a app with a high amount of users.

Comment: The where would not affect you much depending on the size of your dataset, and even then, there are ways to keep a good performance. You can check [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html) blog to read more about this.